# check file in folder, if doesn't contain pdf it will skip the next process

Tags: php

I wanna check folder, if it contain PDF it will go to other process, if doesn't contain PDF, it will skip the process.
here's the code :

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$savePath  = 'D:/AppServ/www/aca/';

$dir      = opendir($savePath);
$check    = glob($savePath.'*.pdf');
if($check === ''){ exit();} // if not found pdf don't do process below this

// many other process below 
?>
```

but the process still run, how to break it ? thank you :)

Comment: Keep in mind that using the "file name extension" to determine the type of file is pretty 80ish...

Answer (score 0):

`glob` returns an empty array when there are no matches, but you're testing for if it's equal to an empty string. Check if the array is empty instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    $savePath  = 'D:/AppServ/www/aca/';

    $dir      = opendir($savePath);
    $check    = glob($savePath.'*.pdf');
    if(empty($check)){ exit();} // if not found pdf don't do process below this

    // many other process below 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!count($check))
    exit;
```

You're comparing `$check` with a string which will always return false.